# check jlist elements is already in another jlist

Tags: java, swing

how to check an element in jlist is already in another jlist
me using java swing.

### my java Code:

lst3mdl-jlist model of 1st jlist

lst2mdl-jlist model of 2nd jlist

AbsntList-second jlist

prsntList-first jlist

---

```
lst2mdl=(DefaultListModel) AbsntList.getModel();/**/------------for checking if element         already exists in jlist "listAbsnt"**

lst3mdl=(DefaultListModel)prsntList.getModel();
                    if(lst2mdl.contains(dsplList.getSelectedValue()||lst3mdl.contains(dsplList.getSelectedValue()))
```

//--do not allow multiple jlist entry

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Element Already exist \n in one of other two List...!");
    else {
        lst1mdl=(DefaultListModel) dsplList.getModel(); 
        int ind=dsplList.getSelectedIndex();
        lst2mdl.addElement(dsplList.getSelectedValue());
        if(ind!=-1)lst1mdl.remove(ind);
```

==========================
**i got this error....**

**am doing  hostel mgmt project in java swing, this jlist come in "Hostel Attendance" module.

can any suggest better **attendance** mgmt method for hostel .
am using xmaplet software for Data base..
**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$3 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
    at hostel.gui.attendanceGUI.hstlattendgui$2.actionPerformed(hstlattendgui.java:135)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: MAN...... i found soln my self............                                ok  the answer is  :                           IllegalArgumentException if model is null

Comment: Did't got Idea ok here it is : if jlist content is null then it throws the above mentioned exception, then use try catch exception handling.... put checking code in try and if throws any exception the write code in catch block or simply Display a message that "the jlist is empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast like this

```
ListModel lst1mdl = dsplList.getModel();
```

with out casting to (DefaultListModel).

Answer (score 2):

Go through the second list model and compare each item with selected element from the first model. If `equals()` returns `true` the second list contains the selected element.

Comment: tnk u 4 ur cmt; but u don't need iterating through each element just take model of the jlist to check, and do 'if(jlistmodel.contains(selected element)..'

Comment: *"tnk u 4 ur cmt"*  I'm sorry, I don't speak "Lazy Teenager".  Can you translate that mess to **English?**